# Does Python PIL resize the image when the dimensions are the same?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, keras

I have a huge dataset of images which are fetched by the Keras Generator and it seems the generator uses PIL to read and resize the images.

The generator asks for a `target_size` to be given which has a default value of `[256,256]`.

I'd like to remove the overhead of resizing the images when the generator is fetching them, so I wanted to know if it would help to resize the images once offline and then use the generator to read the files (hopefully without the overhead)?

Would PIL ignore resizing the images once it checks that the `target_size` is the same as the image dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code of `Image.resize()`

```
if self.size == size:
    return self._new(self.im)
```

When the output size is the same as the input size, it doesn't perform resize but make a new copy of the input.

Comment: thanks... by the way is there a way to avoid this and just return the image (without the overhead of creating a new copy) ?

Comment: Are your images already in the default size for your network? If so, try passing `target_size=None` when creating image generator.

Comment: Didn't work! the generator blurted out an error about it! I didn't check it on PIL individually...